# C# in Visual Basic- How do you add integers from parallel arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

So I have the arrays set up and they are assigned to a value in the design Main Window view. It's set up like a quiz and each question (if statement) is a question with different point values. I just can't figure out how to add all the points for each question up at the end.

```
namespace ParallelArrRbnQuiz
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string[] arrUserAnswer = new string[10];
        int[] arrPoints = new int[10];
        string[] arrCorrectAnswer = new string[10];
        int intScore = 0;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            arrCorrectAnswer[0] = "Loop";
            arrCorrectAnswer[1] = "Conditional";
            arrCorrectAnswer[2] = "Variable";
            arrCorrectAnswer[3] = "Java";
            arrCorrectAnswer[4] = "Decision";
            arrCorrectAnswer[5] = "XAML";
            arrCorrectAnswer[6] = "Compiler";
            arrCorrectAnswer[7] = "Array";
            arrCorrectAnswer[8] = "Syntax Error";
            arrCorrectAnswer[9] = "Camel Casing";

            arrPoints[0] = 5;
            arrPoints[1] = 10;
            arrPoints[2] = 15;
            arrPoints[3] = 5;
            arrPoints[4] = 10;
            arrPoints[5] = 20;
            arrPoints[6] = 5;
            arrPoints[7] = 5;
            arrPoints[8] = 5;
            arrPoints[9] = 20;

            arrUserAnswer[0] = "Loop";
            arrUserAnswer[1] = "Conditional";
            arrUserAnswer[2] = "Variable";
            arrUserAnswer[3] = "Java";
            arrUserAnswer[4] = "Decision";
            arrUserAnswer[5] = "XAML";
            arrUserAnswer[6] = "Compiler";
            arrUserAnswer[7] = "Array";
            arrUserAnswer[8] = "Syntax Error";
            arrUserAnswer[9] = "Camel Casing";
        }
        private void Submit_Answers(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(arrCorrectAnswer[0] == arrUserAnswer[0])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[0];
            }
            if(arrCorrectAnswer[1] == arrUserAnswer[1])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[1];
            }
            if(arrCorrectAnswer[2] == arrUserAnswer[2])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[2];
            }
            if(arrCorrectAnswer[3] == arrUserAnswer[3])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[3];
            }
            if(arrCorrectAnswer[4] == arrUserAnswer[4])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[4];
            }
            if(arrCorrectAnswer[5] == arrUserAnswer[5])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[5];
            }
            if(arrCorrectAnswer[6] == arrUserAnswer[6])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[6];
            }
            if(arrCorrectAnswer[7] == arrUserAnswer[7])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[7];
            }
            if(arrCorrectAnswer[8] == arrUserAnswer[8])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[8];

            if(arrCorrectAnswer[9] == arrUserAnswer[9])
            {
                intScore += arrPoints[9];
            }
                txtScore.Text = intScore.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is a little confusing. Can you clarify? If youre testing user responses against correct responses, thats good, but then why do you change the points values in the points array? That doesn't make sense; i figured youd loop, check for equality, and add points if equal.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the confusion, I'm new to programming and I've been having some trouble getting used to c#. But I've updated my code and it should make a bit more sense now. I hope this helps clarify!

Comment: It makes more sense, thanks. See Shweta's answer for what i would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understand from your code

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(arrCorrectAnswer[i] == arrUserAnswer[i])
    {
        arrPoints[i] += arrPoints[i];
    }
}
```

and then

```
int TotalPoints = 0;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    TotalPoints += arrPoints[i];
}
```

**But I believe it should be**

```
int TotalPoints = 0;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(arrCorrectAnswer[i] == arrUserAnswer[i])
    {
        TotalPoints += arrPoints[i];
    }
}
```

After that you can show `TotalPoints`

Comment: Ok thank you! So I got the code to add up and display in the text box in the design view, but when I do the score (totalpoints), it always adds up to 25 instead of 100. Do you also happen to know how to fix this? Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter to go through each element in the array. You could create a method that does something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
while (counter <= arrPoints.Length(){
    counter += arrPoints[counter]
}
return counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) Linq Extension method to get the total of your array.
(*note: FrameWork 3.5 and greater*)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arrPoints = new int[] { 5, 10, 15, 5, 10, 20, 5, 5, 5, 20 } ;
    int value = arrPoints.Sum();
    Console.WriteLine(value);
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```